# Mocking Service call which call a different class

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

HI I am trying to mock service which internally calls a different class for the execution .Do I need to Mock that class as well.
Below is the code snippet.
I am Mocking class B .My question is how to handle entityDtoConversion class here.Should I really Mock it ?

```
class B {

    public UserFormResponseDto getFormForFormId(String formId) {

        Form form = formRepository.findByUrlFormId(formId);

        UserFormResponseDto userFormResponseDto = null;

        if (form == null) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("Form not found for formId : - " + formId);
        } else {
            userFormResponseDto = entityDtoConversion.convertToUserFormResponseDto(form, false);
        }

        return userFormResponseDto;
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the test class / method you wrote

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: If you are really mocking class `B`, then the real implementation of `getFormForFormId` is never called and you need not worry about `entityDtoConversion`. If it is being called, you are probably not mocking it. Providing the test code would help a lot in determining the issue...

Comment: Yes I am mocking Class B  here is the test code

Comment: @Test
    public void testgetFormByFormId(){
        UserFormResponseDto userFormResponseDto=new UserFormResponseDto();

        userFormResponseDto.setUrlFormId("1234");

        Form form=new Form();

        Mockito.doReturn(userFormResponseDto).when(B).getFormByPid("1234","1");
        

        UserFormResponseDto formByFormId = controller.getFormByFormId("1234");

        Assert.assertNotNull(formByFormId);

        Assert.assertEquals("1234",formByFormId.getUrlFormId());

    }